Why would Instance startup take more than 42 minutes to start?
I have a scaling group (ASG) which I use to keep instances ready for a task. Instance is detached from the ASG when needed and ASG starts another instance when needed.
The instance type is c6g.4xlarge. OS is ubuntu 22.04
Below is the log showing the startup time.
systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4.850s (kernel) + 42min 16.004s (userspace) = 42min 20.854s.

I can see multiple of these failing SSM logs
ERROR [Registrar] failed to register identity: error calling RegisterManagedInstance API: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://ssm.us-xxxx-x.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:xx: i/o timeout
INFO [Registrar] sleeping for 18.7 minutes before retrying registration

This is happening for only a few percent of instances and I am not able to figure out a pattern.

That's an unusual way to use autoscaling groups. Do you have an SSM endpoint in your VPC? It looks like a communications error. Check NACLs, security groups, routes.

Is it unusual?
For my usecase I need instances which are ready to use because Its for a feature where client can request that operation anytime and that operation processing should start immediately.
Is there a better way?

I guess that makes sense. Unusual doesn't mean wrong :) If you could use a lambda function that may be cheaper, but often not practical. As to why the instance is sometimes taking 42 minutes to start... I would look at the logs, perhaps syslog, any log you can find. My best guess is some kind of a timeout... and you have posted a timeout already connecting to the SSM endpoint, but it being intermitted is odd. If you can't get anyone with a solution here suggest you try AWS Support, they're quite effective.

@Tim I asked this question on reddit there they suggested that it might be a subnet issue, the ASG usage multiple subnets and I was able to find a common subnet between all the instances with this issue.

It is a subnet issue. The ASG being used had multiple subnets and one of the subnets was causing this issue. I verified it by going through all the instances with this issue and all of those instances had the same ASG.
